# Jersey Web Service

Tags: json, request, jersey-2.0

I am using Jersey Rest Service. I am getting clients requests in json and getting java object out of it. Everything works fine. However, is there anyway I can get the exact json that was pass from client without even converting to java object.

Issue is json request contents just two parameters and below ObjectMapper converts back to Json but with null values. To ignore, I have to put @JsonInclude(Include.NON_NULL) on each pojo class. If I can get just client json, then it would be good.

ObjectMapper mapper=new ObjectMapper();
String jsonString= mapper.writeValueAsString(body);

Comment: Is your question more about how to use NOT_NULL at a global level? i'm not sure if I understand what you trying to ask.

Comment: No, I just need the json payload which is coming from client without even converting it to the java object in JAX-RS

Comment: In your resource function set the payload as a String and also set the Accepts to text/plain.

Comment: Thank you. Is there any way I can have both

Comment: Is there anyway I can have both  @Consumes({ "application/json" })
@Consumes({ "text/plain" })

Answer (score 0):

Keep the following in your resource method:

```
@Consumes("application/json")
public Response fn(String payload){} //Notice the payload of type string.
```

That way the payload will be just a String. I am still not sure why you want it this way, but it should work.